# Google Translate keyboard shortcut in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-translate

I want to do this:

- Select some text (in Chrome)
- Press a keyboard shortcut
- Get a translation of that text on the same page (some bubble with the translation or something)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

From https://chrome.googleblog.com/2014/10/translate-web-pages-more-easily-with.html

> When you're browsing the web, you might come across a page where some
>   of the text is in a different language. With the new update to the
>   Google Translate Chrome extension, you can translate just that piece
>   of text, without worrying about the rest of the page.

[Google Translate Extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb)

The above extension could be configured to

1. to show a inline button
2. to show the translation popup
3. to show nothing

but it doesn't include keyboard shortcuts.

I just found another extension that could help:

[Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck?hl=en) but I didn't figured out yet exactly how to use it with Google Translate.

Comment: That is the closest thing to what I was looking for. Although it's annoying to get pop-up for everything you select... I have a mouse with a button that is useless for me right now, but to which you can assign a key combination. I wanted to select some text, and then get translation on a click of that button

Comment: Sorry, I posted and unfinished answer. Regarding Google Translate, I think that the referred chrome extension is what is available at this time but probably that could be used together with the Chrome shortcuts. Checkout https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en. By the way, maybe this question should be migrated to [su] because a complete answer will require more about Chrome than about Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

I think - if you can type in javascript - you can install sth like "TamperMonkey" from Google Extensions. You will be able to run any js code on every page. So, you can run in it this:

```
$(function(){
$(document.body).bind('mouseup', function(e){
    var selection;
    
    if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
      selection = document.selection.createRange();
    }
    
    selection.toString() !== '' && window.open("https://translate.google.cz/?text="+selection.toString());
   });
});
```